# Owl Carousel broke my menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am using this template : https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/editorial/

When I put Owl carousel in a `<section>` the `display: block;` broke my menu.

I can't open the menu anymore.

Is there a solution?

Is there another carousel that is responsive and customizable that I should use?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, maybe try setting z-index of menu higher than rest, hope this helps